# Better fits for a linear model

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, nlme

I am fitting some lines and I feel like I am telling R exactly how to fit them, but I feel like there is something (some factor or effect) I am unaware of that is preventing a good fit.

My experimental unit is "plot" as in field plot, which I am sorry is confusing.

The data can be found: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a0tplyvs8lxu1d0/rootmeansv2.csv .
with

```
df$plot.f<-as.factor(df$plot)
dfG<-groupedData(mass ~ year|plot.f, data=df)
dfG30<-dfG[dfG$depth == 30,]
```

Simply, I have mass over time and I fit it to each experimental unit with the model:

```
fit <- lme(mass ~ year , random = ~ 1 | plot, data = df)
```

and with `plot (augPred(fit))` I get these fits for each experimental unit ("plot"):

[image]

What do I need to do to let the slope vary more between experimental units?  I am not interested in this from a statistical perspective, but from a predictive perspective -- so anything in the model can be manipulated to get those lines to move.

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, you do a random slope by `random = ~ 1 + time | eu`.

Comment: Thank you, @RomanLuštrik, but the figure is identical with that code.

Comment: Thanks for posting data, but I can't quite reproduce: are you using a particular subset of the data, e.g. `depth==5`?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I am trying to fit by each depth.  For this figure, depth == 30.

Comment: working on this, but an interim answer is that centering your `year` variable and following Roman's suggestion of including the year x plot interaction appears to work nicely.

Comment: I also realized that I was plotting data that was grouped, so I added the code for that.  I can't get the figure without the grouping.  Using the addition from Roman and no grouping, I can't get a figure, but `coef` shows only tiny, tiny differences in slopes and intercepts.

Comment: Did you center `year`?  That's absolutely critical.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by centering year, so I'm guessing I didn't.  The code I've included above is all I have done.

Comment: He means that instead of using `year` as is, you may need to transform it by subtracting the mean, i.e. "centering".

Comment: yes: for convenience, I used `c. <- function(x) scale(x,center=TRUE,scale=FALSE); lme(mass ~ c.(year), random=~c.(year)|plot, data=gdf)`

Comment: That looks great!!!  Would some one like to post an answer that includes centering for year and adding "time" in the random effects?  I'm a little scared I haven't heard of centering before, because I have already run a lot of models.  When I find a good link about centering, I'll include it here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This answer is going to be a bit encyclopedic, because there are several important points about your question.  **tl;dr** adding `year*plot` as a random effect is the first step, but the fit is actually a bit problematic, although it doesn't appear so at first:  centering the `year` variable takes care of the problem, but log-transforming the data might be an even better idea.

**UPDATE**: OP was doing an analysis on `subset(df,Depth==30)`.  I accidentally did the analysis on the full data set, which may have made things harder -- the heteroscedasticity documented below probably isn't as bad for a subset of the data -- but I'm going to leave it as is for pedagogical purposes (and out of laziness).

Get the data:

```
df <- read.csv("rootmeansv2.csv")
library(nlme)
gdf <- groupedData( mass ~ year | plot, data=df)
```

Adding the year-by-plot interaction to the model as a random effect:

```
fit0 <- lme(mass ~ year , random = ~ year | plot, data = gdf)
```

However, if we look at the results we see that this doesn't help very much at all -- the `year` term (among-plot variance in the slope) is tiny.

```
##             Variance     StdDev       Corr  
## (Intercept) 9.522880e-12 3.085916e-06 (Intr)
## year        7.110616e-08 2.666574e-04 0.32  
## Residual    3.885373e-01 6.233276e-01
```

This does sometimes happen (a singular fit), but otherwise the `lme` summary doesn't indicate in any other way that there might be something wrong.  However, if we try to get confidence intervals we see there might be trouble:

```
 intervals(fit0)
 ##   Error in intervals.lme(fit0) : 
 ##   cannot get confidence intervals on var-cov components: Non-positive definite approximate variance-covariance
```

The other way to double-check is to fit the same model in `lme4`.

```
library(lme4)
VarCorr(fit1 <- lmer(mass ~ year +(year | plot), data = gdf))

##  Groups   Name        Std.Dev.   Corr  
##  plot     (Intercept) 0.66159674       
##           year        0.00059471 -1.000
##  Residual             0.62324403       
## Warning messages:
## 1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
##   Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.132739 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
## 2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
##   Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
```

We get apparently quite different answers, and warnings about convergence (this is in the development version, 1.1-7, which does not suffer from the false-positive warnings reported widely for 1.1-6).  It looks like `lme4`'s fit is slightly better:

```
c(logLik(fit1)-logLik(fit0))
## 0.1775161
```

One of the potential data problems for complex fits such as mixed models is poor centering and scaling of predictor variables.  In this case, because `year` is a continuous predictor that starts at 2008, the intercept and slopes are **extremely** highly correlated (the intercept is the predicted value in year 0!).  We can fix the problem in this case by centering -- it would also be reasonable to subtract the minimum (i.e. start year at 0 rather than 2008)

```
c. <- function(x) scale(x,center=TRUE,scale=FALSE)
VarCorr(fit2 <- update(fit1,.~ c.(year) +(c.(year) | plot)))

##  Groups   Name        Std.Dev. Corr 
##  plot     (Intercept) 0.53798       
##           c.(year)    0.10515  1.000
##  Residual             0.59634
```

We get more reasonable answers (and no warnings), although we do still have perfectly (now positively) correlated intercepts and slopes -- this just says the model is slightly overfitting the data, but there's not much we can do about this (we could force the correlation to zero by fitting the model `~c.(year)+(c.(year)||plot))`, but this has its own problems).

Now try it in `lme`:

```
VarCorr(fit3 <- update(fit0,
                       fixed.=~c.(year),
                       random=~c.(year)|plot,
         control=lmeControl(opt="optim")))
## plot = pdLogChol(c.(year)) 
##             Variance   StdDev    Corr  
## (Intercept) 0.28899909 0.5375864 (Intr)
## c.(year)    0.01122497 0.1059479 0.991 
## Residual    0.35559015 0.5963138
```

Results are similar (although correlation is only 0.991 instead of 1.0): the difference in log-likelihoods is actually slightly larger, but still small.  (The fit is still somewhat problematic -- I had to change optimizers as shown in the `lmeControl` argument to get here.)

Things now look better:

```
plot(augPred(fit3))
```

[image]

However, the residual vs fitted plot shows you a problem you should worry about:

```
plot(fit3)
```

[image]

The funnel shape shows you have a heteroscedasticity problem. The scale-location plot shows it even more clearly:

```
plot(fit3,sqrt(abs(resid(.)))~fitted(.),type=c("p","smooth"))
```

[image]

The most obvious fix is to log-transform the data:

```
df$logmass <- log10(df$mass)  ## log10() for interpretability
gdfL <- groupedData( logmass ~ year | plot, data=df)
VarCorr(fitL1 <- lme(logmass ~ c.(year) , random = ~ c.(year) | plot,
             data = gdfL))
## plot = pdLogChol(c.(year)) 
##             Variance     StdDev     Corr  
## (Intercept) 0.1842905872 0.42929080 (Intr)
## c.(year)    0.0009702893 0.03114947 -0.607
## Residual    0.1052946948 0.32449144
```

The among-year variation is small again, but this time it's probably because it's not needed.  There are no warnings from `lmer` when we fit the equivalent model, and we get identical results; fit is non-singular (no zero variances or perfect correlations); and `intervals(fitL1)` works.

The predictions look reasonable:

```
plot(augPred(fitL1))
```

[image]

So does the diagnostic plot:

```
plot(fitL1)
```

[image]

Although there does appear to be something a bit funny about 2008 (the axes are flipped because `lme` prefers to plot boxplots horizontally -- `factor(year)` tells `lme` to use a boxplot instead of a scatterplot).

```
plot(fitL1,factor(year)~resid(.))
```

[image]

Comment: +1 -- this is great! Ben, I can not reproduce the results. I think it is because the subset does not work and you are using the entire data set (should be depth==30 instead of depth=30)

Comment: see edits.  Presumably your particular problem is resolved, though? (Do you see any heteroscedasticity with the `depth==30` subset?)

Comment: This is just great! I do keep Pinheiro and Bates close at all times, but I often need a second source like this.

Comment: @BenBolker, with depth==30 the heteroscedasticity problem persists. The problem now is that fitL1 model (the one with lme) does not converge. The model fitL2 with lmer works well. Also, the last boxplot shows a curious behavior for year 2008.