# How to compute reliability estimates from lmer / lme results?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

*Disclaimer: Sorry for including images. I tried writing formulas in markdown format but failed*

I'm coming from a commercial MLM (HLM7) software and would like to replicate some numbers in R.

Specifically i'm looking for a function or formula computing the **reliability for the least squares estimates of each level1 coefficient across the set of *J* level-2 units**

Below is an example based on the simple `sleepstudy` data. What I'm looking for is a way to compute reliability values not only in this very example, but also in situations where there are more level1 variables.

From HLM7 manual (Raudenbush, Bryk (2002), p.11) a definition of reliability is given:
[image]

Equation 3.58 in Hierarchical Linear Models (2nd ed.)

[image]

which is followed by the notion that:
[image]

I used the `sleepstudy` data from `lme4` package to compute a random intercept and slope model with `lme4::lmer`:

```
library(lme4)
m <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), data = sleepstudy)
summary(m)
```

And with HLM7 software

[image]

Fixed and random effects estimates are pretty similar (differences in rounding occur), but HLM7 will also provide it's reliability estimates:

```
 ----------------------------------------------------
  Random level-1 coefficient   Reliability estimate
 ----------------------------------------------------
  INTRCPT1, G0                        0.730
      DAYS, G1                        0.815
 ----------------------------------------------------
```

And this is something I'd like to be able to get from `lmer()` results.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have a look at these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198958/extracting-coefficients-and-their-standard-error-from-lme 
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072544/how-to-get-coefficients-and-their-confidence-intervals-in-mixed-effects-models 
Google will probably give you some more results

Answer (score 1):

I needed to include reliability measures for a school project and could not find any package that provided these values. Thus, I had to create them via dplyr:
parameter variance/(parameter variance + (residual variance/n clusters)). Hope this helps should anyone else seek the answer to this question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).